# What is a good continuous localization workflow for a website?

Tags: continuous-integration, internationalization, google-translate

I just started looking into translating our React website to different languages. I have a proof of concept working with react-i18next.

The next problem I have is continuous localization.

What I mean by that is, if I need to change or add new text as part of an A/B test or a new feature, I need a workflow for updating the translations.

Reaching out to the translators every time I need to translate a new phrase doesn't seem like the most efficient thing to do. It might not even be worth billing.

This sounds like a common problem, so I'd like to hear what workflows everyone is following to tackle something like this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To best implement continuous localization, I suggest to separate translations from your code completely. Also hosting the translations to a different place, i.e. a CDN.
There are some services, like [locize](https://locize.com) that enables such a workflow.
A good example on how you could unleash the full power of react-i18next with such a continuous localization workflow can be found in this tutorial: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb